# TD background with two colors

Tags: html, css

A quick question here, `css3 gradient` is not helping in my requirement. I need to highlight `td` with two colors, left half with one color and right half with other color.

**Output should be:**

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why is a gradient not helping? Can you show an image of your expected output?

Comment: Is it a `td` on its own? It'll need to be inside a `table` and such.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to achieve what you need with gradients. Can you include the code of the gradient that you had tried?

Comment: you can do this with gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need like this.
I don't Know whether it is correct or not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                background: linear-gradient( to right, #ff9e2c 0%, #ff9e2c 50%, #FF0000 50%, #FF0000 100%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Savings</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>$100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Feb</td>
                <td>$1000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>March</td>
                <td>$10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>April</td>
                <td>$110</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/17d80ym3/10/

Answer (score 1):

try this it will work 100%;

```
HTML:
<table >
<tr><td>welcome</td><td>welcome</td></tr>
</table>

css
table
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
  table tr td
  {
    width:200px;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%);
    background-position:top left;
    text-align:center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  color:#fff;
  }
```

Comment: try this link   https://jsfiddle.net/mhrjnsa1/17d80ym3/3/ @Akki619

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
background: rgb(91, 155, 213);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(91,155,213,1) 0%,rgba(91,155,213,1) 50%,rgba(158,191,229,1) 50%,rgba(158,191,229,1) 100%);
width:100px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```